# How to arrange array with proper value in main array

Tags: php, arrays

currently i am trying to assign value in array , this is my existing array looks like..

```
Array
(
    [detals] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [make] => xyx
                    [yeardeta] => 2001
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test one
                            [1] => test fix
                            [2] => Hamour
                            [3] => Imagica
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [make] => xyx
                    [yeardeta] => 2002
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test Two
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

I Want it output like this ..

```
Array
(
    [detals] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [make] => xyx
                    [yeardeta] => 2001
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test one
                            [1] => test fix
                            [2] => Hamour
                            [3] => Imagica
                        )
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [make] => xyx
                    [yeardeta] => 2002
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test Two
                        )

                )


        )

)
```

And this is my full PHP code

```
<?php
$data = array();
 $cat = get_terms('car_category');
        foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
                   $term_id =$catVal->term_id;

                    $get_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta as pm
                         LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr
                         ON tr.object_id=pm.post_id
                         WHERE pm.meta_key='car_year'
                         AND tr.term_taxonomy_id='".$term_id."'");

                foreach ($get_query as $key => $value) {

                    $data[] = array('make'=>$catVal->term_id,'yeardeta'=>$value->meta_value);

                         $get_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts as p
                                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pm
                                ON p.id=pm.post_id
                                LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr
                                ON tr.object_id=pm.post_id
                                WHERE pm.meta_key='car_year'
                                AND pm.meta_value='".$value->meta_value."'
                                AND tr.term_taxonomy_id='".$term_id."'");
                         $str = array();
                         foreach ($get_query as $key => $value) {
                              $str[] = $value->post_title;
                        }

                        $data[] = array('model'=>$str);

                }

                $term_id =$catVal->term_id;

                $main_array = array('detals'=>$data);

            print_r($main_array);

        }

?>
```

i want to output that i have explain above How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code which pasted bellow. In your loop you used `$data[]` twice thus new array element inserted. Please check following code (I could not test), modify as required and let me know for any clarifications:

```
<?php
$data = array();
$cat = get_terms('car_category');
foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
    $term_id =$catVal->term_id;

    $get_query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta as pm
         LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr
         ON tr.object_id=pm.post_id
         WHERE pm.meta_key='car_year'
         AND tr.term_taxonomy_id='".$term_id."'");

    foreach ($get_query as $key => $value) {
        $make = $catVal->term_id;
        $yeardata = $value->meta_value;                    

        $get_query_model = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts as p
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as pm
                ON p.id=pm.post_id
                LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as tr
                ON tr.object_id=pm.post_id
                WHERE pm.meta_key='car_year'
                AND pm.meta_value='".$value->meta_value."'
                AND tr.term_taxonomy_id='".$term_id."'");
        $model = array();
        foreach ($get_query_model as $model_key => $model_value) {
          $model[] = $model_value->post_title;
        }

        $data[] = array('make'=>$make,'yeardata'=>$yeardata, 'model'=>$model);
    }

    $term_id =$catVal->term_id;

    $main_array = array('detals'=>$data);

    print_r($main_array);

}
?>
```

Comment: oh sorry, I will replicate your scenario after some time. if you can fix meantime let me know

Comment: after replacing my code can you please print the output and provide me that data

Comment: i put it under my question see above que.. plz

Comment: take a screenshot of the output and share it using image share tool like https://www.techsmith.com/jing.html

Comment: Ok in your last inner query the variable name is $get_query which replaced by your 2nd last inner query variable $get_query thus in your original code it printed less values then my one. In my sample you will see I used $get_query_model to avoid replacing 2nd last inner query. Please ensure that in every level of loop you have data and ensures that it is not replaced

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$data[] = array('model'=>$str);
```

replace it with

```
$data['model'] = $str;
```

The above one creates a new array inside `$data['newkey']`.

To append -> use the `model` key in `$data`.